# ADFS claims - return effective AD permissions (members of a group that belongs to a group)

Tags: claims-based-identity, adfs

I have ADFS configured to deliver AD group information for a logged in user returned as claims.

Claim Language:
(sorry for the screen capture... the schemas were interpretted as URLs that I wasn't allowed to post)
[Basic claims to return AD groups user belongs to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNuQ0.jpg)

This returns groups that the user directly belongs to.
Would like ADFS to return effective permissions for the user.

**Example:**

User MyDomain\Bob belongs to the group Floor3Employees

The Group EntireBuilding contains the groups Floor1Employees, Floor2Employees, Floor3Employees

When getting claims for MyDomain\Bob... would like the groups returned to be:

- Floor3Employees
- EntireBuilding

The web application receiving the claims from ADFS could probably query AD to figure out the hierarchy of groups, but want to avoid the web application communicating directly with AD.